# Google Colab - How to 'restart runtime' using python code or command line interface?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Can someone suggest me programatically 'restart runtime'? Any programmatically restarting option is fine, python or CLI (Command Line Interface), without using GUI.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Run a cell with the following code snippet:

```
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

That will kill the current Python runtime process, which will be automatically restarted by the manager.

Comment: In this case, the runtime is indeed restarted, but a "Run All" command would be interrupted at this point without resuming. Any way to resume running the notebook?

Comment: No, the runtime 'is' the running notebook. But you can re-run it, and do some checks, like: `try: ... except ImportError: !pip install ... print('Deps installed, run again'); os.kill(...)`. If the runtime is OK, then proceed without restarting.

Comment: Will this restarted run time continue to next 12/24 hours?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore as Colab will see this as a crash and stop running.

Comment: we can also use ```%reset```

Answer (score 15):

To add to Bob's answer - once you kill yourself (which the kernel process is doing), there's no going back.
So you won't be able to programmatically resume the execution after the self-destruct call.

But you can make it work without changing code - i.e. there's a limited number of reasons to restart (e.g. installing modules, especially if they were imported, switching Tensorflow versions etc.), and in your final run of the notebook, they shouldn't be necessary.

Here's a complete example of installing Detectron2 on top of a notebook about object detection:

```py
%%time
# deps installation
try:
  import detectron2
except ImportError:
  !git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2 detectron2_repo
  !pip install -e detectron2_repo
  print('Stopping RUNTIME! Please run again.')
  import os
  os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

Comment: I don't get it, should i put this on top of notebook I want to restart?

Comment: Yes. It will be restarted by Colab, but of course it won't resume executing the cells. So you need to press "run all cells" again. Try/except above just prevents this from happening if the libraries are already installed.

Answer (score 9):

You could simply use:

```
exit()
```

This will restart the runtime without deleting files. The runtime will automatically start. And if you press "run all" the run is not interrupted and works till the end.

Comment: The run is not interrupted, but it goes on without applying the changes (uses old library and DO NOT uses a newly installed library)

Comment: Or maybe just `exit`?