# Need to restart runtime before import an installed package in Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install and use an existing python package in Google Colab. For this, I download the code from Github in Colab and install the package, but when trying to import the installed package, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gem'` Error.

However, if I restart the runtime and run the importing cell again, then no error appears.

I am wondering why I need to restart the runtime after installing the package and before importing.

Any clever response will be much appreciated.

My code is:

```
[1] !wget --show-progress --continue -O /content/gem.zip https://github.com/palash1992/GEM/archive/master.zip

[2] !unzip gem.zip

# Installing Dependencies
[3] ! pip install keras==2.0.2

[4] %cd GEM-master
!sudo python3 setup.py install
%cd-

[5] from gem.utils import graph_util, plot_util
```

And the error that I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-af270a37878a> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 
----> 3 from gem.utils import graph_util, plot_util
      4 from gem.evaluation import visualize_embedding as viz
      5 from gem.evaluation import evaluate_graph_reconstruction as gr

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gem'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I restart the runtime using `os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)` after installing the package and before importing it, then the above error does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that everything except simple `!pip install`s seem to not get included in colab's module registry except after a runtime restart. Likely, colab has a fairly naive way of keeping track of available modules. You also have to restart the runtime if you import a different version of a previously installed package.

Probably they just have a script that appends the metadata for `pip`ly installed packages to a list-like object during runtime. And `import`s just search from the top of the list (which is why the restart is required for diff versions of packages).

However, when a new runtime is started, the list-like registry is initialized and populated by searching the relevant directories.

Comment: So is there any other way to fix this issue other than restarting the runtime?

Comment: Not that I know of... Maybe just collectively spamming Google from Colaboratory to "Report a bug" or "Send feedback" --heh

Comment: Everytime we restart the variables get lost and have to start again from step 1

Answer (score 1):

To force a restart:

```py
try:
  from gem.utils import graph_util, plot_util
except (ImportError, KeyError, ModuleNotFoundError):
  ## code to install gem
  print('Stopping RUNTIME. Colaboratory will restart automatically. Please run again.')
  exit()
```

Based on multiple answers to [Google Colab - How to 'restart runtime' using python code or command line interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53154369/132438).