# Google Colab: problems to run fig.write_image()

Tags: python, plotly, conda, google-colaboratory

I am trying to save a plotly line static image using the next code:

```
import plotly 
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(EFBCg_f[1:12], x='time(ms)', y="C(n)", width=800, height=200)
fig.show()
file='Results/filename.png'
fig.write_image(file)
```

in the site https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/, marks as a request to install eithe:

```
!pip install -U kaleido
```

or

```
conda install -c plotly python-kaleido
```

I do not have problems to install kaleido using pip, but create an empty file.

Therefore, I try to install kaleido using coda, but first I have to install coda because it is not native in Google Colab. I proceed as follows:

!pip install conda

and I do not have problems. Then, I run the command:

```
!conda install -c plotly python-kaleido
```

and I have the next reply:

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

now, I stuck.

I appreciate if you can help to find the problem. Thank you. Juan.

Comment: `pip install` is the way to go here. Are you sure the issue is not your code? E.g., does the example in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-kaleido-b03c4b7b1d81) work?

Answer (score 5):

To save an image from plotly in Google Colab first run:

```
!pip install -U kaleido
```

Then go to `Runtime > Restart Runtime` in the menu.

After restarting runtime, re-run your code. (You don't need to rerun the pip command).

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839010) for why Restart Runtime is sometimes needed to install a package in Google Colab.

Comment: Thanks. Generally after installation of a package if restart of runtime is required a message comes is published in Google Colab. But after installation of kaleido no such message is published.

Comment: Can someone explain why is it necessary to restart the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

try this (tnx to Greg Hogg https://youtu.be/qNF1HqBvpGE)

```
!wget https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.2.1/orca-1.2.1-x86_64.AppImage -O /usr/local/bin/orca

!chmod +x /usr/local/bin/orca

!apt-get install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libgconf-2-4
```