# How to Restart & Run All code if there is a Key Error during a ! pip install in Google Colab?

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, google-colaboratory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Google Colab, when I install & import this code on each run:

```
! pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
! pip install pyspark
! pip install snowflake-connector-python asn1crypto==0.24.0
! pip install azure-storage==0.34.3
! pip install azure.storage.common

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,SQLContext
import pyspark
import snowflake.connector as con
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = pyspark.SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'snowflake-connector-python'
```

I've spoken to Snowflake and they say this is normal and that I just need to click Restart & Run All again.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can automatically Restart & Run All within the code so that I don't need to do this manually? I'm thinking a while loop, but I'm not familiar with error handling during installation.

I'm aware that I can save pip installs to my Drive, but because these files will be acting as shared dashboards, I don't want colleagues to have to do this.

I've read a few things about how to restart the kernel, but not running the whole file again, e.g:

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce - everything install fine for me. Any more details? Why do you want 0.24.0 specifically?

Comment: Hi Felipe, Apologies - I have just updated the code which now reproduces the error in Google Colab. I don't necessarily want version 0.24.0

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could do:

- Try to import a package
- If it fails (KeyError, ImportError, etc), pip install it and force a kernel restart.

```py
try:
  import snowflake.connector as con
except (ImportError, KeyError, ModuleNotFoundError):
  !pip install snowflake-connector-python 
  print('Stopping RUNTIME. Colaboratory will restart automatically. Please run again.')
  exit()
```

Based on multiple answers to [Google Colab - How to 'restart runtime' using python code or command line interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53154369/132438).

Comment: Thanks Felipe :) I've run your code and it seems I still have to manually click 'Run all' from the top menu? Perhaps there's not a way to programatically click 'Run All'?

Comment: I'd say this is the best we can get, unless Colaboratory had an "onload" way to trigger code